# How to print a given number of decimal places?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print my result with a specific number of decimal places inside of a for loop where the value of it is the number of decimal places to be printed.

**Below is a sample of the relevant part of the code**:

```
for i in range (-15, -7):    
    print ('Valor do erro:' , 10**i,  'Valor da serie:', count, '------->', '%.16f' % adder(count))
```

Comment: where is the function `adder` defined.? What does it do.? Include it in the code so that we can reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

Format-specifiers can be nested:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 5):
...     print("{:.{}f}".format(1/i, i))
...
1.0
0.50
0.333
0.2500
```

Here, `1/i` goes to the first (outer) `{...}` and `i` to the second (inner) `{}`.

Note that the number of decimal places can *not* be negative, though. For this, you might just want to use [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) instead.

```
>>> for i in range(-2, 3):
...    print("{:.2e}".format(10**i))
...
1.00e-02
1.00e-01
1.00e+00
1.00e+01
1.00e+02
```

Comment: This results in an error: "ValueError: Format specifier missing precision"

Comment: @PedroUnas Not for me. What version of Python are you using? Also, `i` should probably not ne negative, as in your loop. What precision would you expect then?